# Having a issue processing multiple files at once in a Windows Service with a FileSystemWatcher

Tags: windows, multithreading, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

When I try and process more than a couple of files at the same time (they are created and dumped in a folder at the same time), my service dies.

When I wasn't trying to use a thread and had all the processing (where the code in the ProcessFiles method now is) in the Watcher_Created event, at least one file gets through successfully.

When I added the threading (which I'm pretty sure I have to do for this, but am totally unsure of the exact flow and syntax using the threading), I get the following msg in my ProcessFiles method:

System.ArgumentException: Empty path name is not legal.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)

The above msg occurs on the using line:

```
private static void ProcessFiles()
        {
            try
            {
Thread.Sleep(500);

GetCruiseLineShipName(fullFileName, ref cruiseLine, ref shipName);
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(fullFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
```

which is obvious, because the "fullFileName" is an empty string. However, it does get set in the Watcher_Created event:

```
private static void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            fullFileName = e.FullPath;
        }
```

So, I don't understand why the fullFileName variable is an empty string. I know it must have something to do with the threading I'm trying.

My OnStart event looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\DropOff_FTP\MIS");

            Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Created);
            Watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
            Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            Watcher.InternalBufferSize = 64;

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFiles));
            t.Start();
        }
```

Can someone PLEASE inform me how I can use the FileSystemWatcher to process multiple files that are dumped in there at the same time. If I need to use threading, could you please supply how I would use the thread based on the code above?

btw, I'm using the 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually something is wrong here. If I understand you correctly, you have two files created in the same folder with short time difference. Then you receive the first event and set the name of ONE file in the global variable fullFileName and you expect that the running thread process this file using the global variable, but in the same time another event Created happens and you change the global variable that the separate thread is processing

I will try to change you code in this way:

the `OnStart` method loose the code that starts the Thread

the `Watcher_Created` event will start the thread passing the name of the file that raised the event

```
.....
Thread t = new Thread(ProcessFiles);
t.Start(e.FullPath);
.....
```

the `ProcessFiles` receive the argument with the name of the file to process...

```
public void ProcessFiles(object argument) 
{
      string fullFileName = (string)argument;
      GetCruiseLineShipName(fullFileName, ref cruiseLine, ref shipName);
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(fullFileName, ....))
      .....
}
```

Comment: Steve, thanks so much for replying.... I formatted the code as you suggested. However, if I include a parameter on the t.Start (as you have above), the "Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFiles))" gives me a design time compile err of "No overload for ProcessFiles matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart', meaning I can't pass any paramaters to it. I know iwht the t.Start, there is an option to include a parameter. Are we missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, but fallen on copy/paste. Check the update. No need to use ThreadStart, pass just the method name and the compiler will infer the appropriate delegate (ParametrizedThreadStart)

Comment: If I try running it as you have, the service just stops on the t.Start method with the following error: "ex = {"The thread was created with a ThreadStart delegate that does not accept a parameter."}"

Comment: The method name is just being passed: "Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFiles));" Could you possibly update the code syntax you sent before so I'm in sync with what you're saying? thanks so much for your help....

Comment: But do you have changed the ProcessFile method to receive the argument?

Comment: Yes, but I get a design time compile error on the following line "Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFiles));" saying "No overload for 'ProcessFiles' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'. My 'ProcessFiles' method is as follows: "public static void ProcessFiles(string fullFileName)" and my 'Watcher_Created' event is as follows: "private static void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {try {
 Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFiles));
            t.Start(e.FullPath);

Comment: Look at the updated answer, the code that creates the thread is only `Thread t = new Thread(ProcessFiles));` without the delegate, or you could try with `Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessFiles));`

Comment: I have the 'ProcessFiles' method as follows: "public static void ProcessFiles(string fullFileName)". I have the 'Watcher_Created" event as follows: private static void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFiles(e.FullPath))); As is, I get a design time compile error of "Method name expected" in the 'Watcher_Created method. Can you please write the code the way it should be to avoid any confusion?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21775/discussion-between-steve-and-sagesky36)